# Primes representable by equivalent binary forms

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-forms, discriminant

So the question I have is this , if a prime p is representable by two primitive positive definitive binary quadratic forms f(x,y) and g(x,y) of the same discriminant, are they necessarily equivalent? If so, how do you prove such a thing. I'm studying class groups right now, and this is a question I had. Maybe this has something to do with genera, but I'm neither sure of the answer nor the proof to this.

Comment: yes, either equivalent or opposite, which means the matrix of transition has determinant $-1.$ For example, $2x^2 -xy + 3 y^2$ and $2x^2 + xy + 3y^2$ represent the same numbers, thus the same primes.

Comment: Ok. How would you prove this to be true,that f and g have to be equivalent if they represent the same prime and have the same discriminant?

Comment: Do you have a textbook?

Comment: I have only an expository paper to refer to, and it doesn't really address this directly...

Comment: Wiki's [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_quadratic_form#Reduction_and_class_numbers) doesn't mention the lattice in $\mathbf{Q}(\sqrt{-\Delta})$ associated to the binary form ?